# Sometimes I'm Less, Sometimes I'm More

Tags: pattern

> This is a pattern puzzle >
>
> **.**
>
> The answer to this puzzle is in the text itself <
>
> Do you need some more lines? >
>
> Do you think you are seeing a pattern? <
>
> Well, after this line, that pattern breaks <
>
> The next one has to be this: >
>
> It goes on and on forever <
>
> I will add a new line every day >
>
> The pattern should be for the whole thing >
>
> I added a hint! <
>
> OH MY GOSH I'M HAVING TO SEARCH THINGS UP NOW <

Hint 1:

> To memorize me will be impossible, although some may go very far

Hint 2:

> A special day is dedicated to me, where some eat a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern is based off of

> pi. More specifically, the less than and greater than signs are determined by whether the next digit is less or more than the previous.

It follows the hints because

> there are infinite digits to pi and March 14th is called pi day where people eat pie. Also the "search things up now" comment makes sense since PotatoLatte probably needed to look up the next digit.

Comment: This is correct!

Answer (score 5):

> The number of words per line grows with this: > 
>  And shrinks when using this: <

To clarify, I meant that

> The lines ending with > grow in terms of number of words (5, 6, 7, 8), while the lines ending with < shrink (10, 8, 7, 6).

Comment: If that's true, there's an issue near the end. On the third to last line, the symbol is >, signaling the next line should be longer than the last. However, the third to last line has 7 words, but the next line has 6.

Comment: @KingDedede'sSecretAssistant True, but this break of pattern is hinted at in the line before the one you mention.

Comment: I see your point. Nicely done.

Comment: It has to be for the whole thing, though